# How to unsinstall thunderbird mail in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, software-uninstall

I tried to uninstall Thunderbird Mail with the software updater but the Thuderbird icon is not there! How can i uninstall thunderbird with the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove Thunderbird by running

```
sudo snap remove thuderbird
```

or

```
sudo apt remove --autoremove thunderbird
```

from a terminal window.

Comment: Done! Newby question...should i also thank the others who tried to help  me?

Comment: @Alexboybkk This answer was my comment from above that I just removed now to help not cause confusion.  This is a great site for answers and for learning in all honesty.  If you work on helping others answer their questions you will gain a lot of knowledge.  That is what I do here.  It is great to come in and refresh my knowledge or learn something new in the process.  Have a great time!